# Triangle in space

Tags: pstricks, pst-solides3d

I would like to draw the following surface in space using `\psSolid` command:

`$\{(x,y,z): x + 2y + 3z = 4, x \geq 0, y \geq 0, z \geq 0\}$`.

Here it is the best I can get:

```
\psset{unit=0.5cm}
\psset[pst-solides3d]{viewpoint=40 30 25 rtp2xyz,Decran=60,fontsize=0}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(3,10)
\defFunction[algebraic]{tri}(u,v){u}{v}{4/3 - u/3 - 2*v/3}
\psSolid[algebraic,object=surfaceparametree,base=0 2 0 2, linewidth=0.5pt, function=tri, ngrid=10 30, fillcolor=yellow, incolor=white]%
\axesIIID[showOrigin=false,linewidth=1.5pt,arrowinset=0,arrows=->, arrowscale=1.2, labelsep=7pt](0,0,0)(3,3,5)
\end{pspicture}
```

The parameter v depends on u, that is, u = 0..4 and v = 0..2 - u/2 but how can I declare this in the base? There is some way to do this with \psSolid? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the equation as definition:

```
\psSolid[object=plan,definition=equation,args={[1 2 3 -4]},
     base=0 2 0 2,linewidth=0.5pt,fillcolor=yellow,plangrid,ngrid=4 4]%
```

Comment: That's not look like a triangle...

Comment: then you do not have `x \geq 0, y \geq 0, z \geq 0`